# Error while creating mount source path when using docker-compose in Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to dockerize my React-Flask app by dockerizing each one of them and using `docker-compose` to put them together.

Here the `Dockerfile`s for each app look like:

**React - Frontend**

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /frontend/

ENV PATH /frontend/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /frontend/package.json
COPY . /frontend/
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g --silent

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

**Flask - Backend**

```
#Using ubuntu as our base
FROM ubuntu:latest

#Install commands in ubuntu, including pymongo for DB handling
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
RUN python -m pip install pymongo[srv]

#Unsure of COPY command's purpose, but WORKDIR points to /backend
COPY . /backend
WORKDIR /backend/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

#Run order for starting up the backend
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Each of them works fine when I just use `docker build` and `docker up`. I've checked that they work fine when they are built and ran independently. However, when I `docker-compose up` the `docker-compose.yml` which looks like

```
# Docker Compose
version: '3.7'

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - '.:/frontend'
      - '/frontend/node_modules'
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
       - .:/code
```

Gives me the error below

```
Starting frontend                ... error
Starting dashboard_backend_1 ...

ERROR: for frontend  Cannot start service sit-frontend: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/c/Users/myid/DeskStarting dashboard_backend_1 ... error

ERROR: for dashboard_backend_1  Cannot start service backend: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/c/Users/myid/Desktop/dashboard': mkdir /host_mnt/c: file exists

ERROR: for frontend  Cannot start service frontend: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/c/Users/myid/Desktop/dashboard': mkdir /host_mnt/c: file exists

ERROR: for backend  Cannot start service backend: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/c/Users/myid/Desktop/dashboard': mkdir /host_mnt/c: file exists
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Did this happen because I am using Windows? What can be the issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24):

For me the only thing that worked was restarting the Docker deamon

Comment: Also I had to remove the volume prior to restarting.

Answer (score 6):

Check if this is related to [docker/for-win issue 1560](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1560)

> I had the same issue. I was able to resolve it by running:
>
> ```
> docker volume rm -f [name of docker volume with error]
> ```
>
> Then restarting docker, and running:
>
> ```
> docker-compose up -d --build
> ```
>
> I tried these same steps without restarting my docker, but restarting my computer and that didn't resolve the issue.
> What resolved the issue for me was removing the volume with the error, restarting my docker, then doing a build again.

Other cause:

> On Windows this may be due to a user password change. Uncheck the box to stop sharing the drive and then allow Docker to detect that you are trying to mount the drive and share it.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/470472/36745728-49101172-1ba5-11e8-94da-1386cfba9702.png]

Also mentioned:

> - I just ran `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up`. Worked for me.
> - I have tried with `docker container prune` then press `y` to remove all stopped containers. This issue has gone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When you say `[name of docker volume with error]`, what would this be and how can I check?

Comment: @Dawn17 [docker volume ls](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_ls/) should give you the exiting created volume.

Comment: It shows me multiple volumes and doesn't indicate which one has an error. Shall I just try to remove all of them?

Comment: @Dawn17 Check first the other options presented in that issue.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this after I deleted a folder I'd shared with docker and recreated one with the same name. I think this deleted the permissions. To resolve it I:

- Unshared the folder in docker settings
- Restarted docker
- Ran docker container prune
- Ran docker-compose build
- Ran docker-compose up.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the docker daemon will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).